# How to add Clicked event handler for a designer-created menu item in .Net Core Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, .net-core, menu

I am at the beginning of the process of moving from .Net Framework to .Net Core. Concretely, I am trying to create a simple Winforms application with a menu. The menu consists of a number of `MenuItem`s, of which each may have a few `DropDownItem`s.

In .Net Visual Studio Designer for a Framework project the task is trivial, you simply type the name of the handler method in the event tab of the property grid for the menu item. As far as I can see, it is different with .Net core. I can create menu items and their children, though, but there is no event tab (or at least I found none). Does this mean that I need to add the event handlers manually? (Cannot believe it.)

I was unable to find an answer or a hint elsewhere.

Environment: VS 2019, Windows 10, Microsoft.NETCore.App Version 3.1.0

As far as I understand this article: [.NET Core 3 for Windows Desktop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-for-windows-desktop/), it might be that the .NET core winforms designer simply does not have this feature (which would be equivalent to the necessity to create menus by hand or porting from .Net framework)?